# Red 5 publish Issue

Tags: red5

I m publishing a stream on red5 using microphone on client side as3 code .  but it not published good stream but the same thing i m doing on FMS it creates perfect stream 
I need to be understand what is the issue during publish on red 5 .

Answer (score 0):

Read Red5 documentation for that. And ofcourse there are differences between the performances of the two servers. However if you want to improve the quality of stream you can use FFMPEG or Xuggler with Red5 to encode streams.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not saying what your encoder is, it is hard to give a clear answer.  If you are using Adobe's FMLE to create the stream that goes to your FMS server, it is the FMLE that explains why you have good video and audio encoding 'out-of-the-box'.

I have never tried to use FMLE with RED5, so I cannot tell you if it works, but doubtful it works out-of-the-box. It probably can work with a bit of tweaking on both client and server side.

To use your own encoder, what you do is capture two streams using ffmpeg, a great example on how to do that is on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311560/how-can-i-capture-audio-and-video-simultenaous-with-ffmpeg-from-an-usb-capture-d).

Once you are capturing, you can use ffmpeg to send the combined audio and video streams to a file, or you can send it directly to your red 5 server. A simplified version of the ffmpeg command to show mapping two streams to give a single rtmp output is shown below.

```
ffmpeg -i video_stream -i audio_stream -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -f flv rtmp://my.red5.server:1935/live/mystream
```